# Azure LogicApps: Conversion from String to Float returns zero

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, data-conversion

I am surprised to see this, but I witness that in some instance the string value aren't converting as expected to float; mostly returns zero.

The following image shows what happens. As you see I have 2 variables namely `var_MarginStr` of type `string` and `var_MarginValues` of type `float` in my Logic App. I am assigning `var_MarginVal` as follows:

`var_MarginVal = float(string(variables('var_MarginStr')))`

[image]

[image]

In my working where I trigger my logic app after a new blob is inserted into a blob storage account. The content(*.csv) of the blob is passed to an Azure Function which returns a `JSON` object. The JSON object is then being looped over each item and is sent to my DB via a Stored Proc.

I have checked my Azure Function which converts the content to JSON working perfectly and the response from such is:

```
{
  "fileName": "20200307-PLC-JKB-Margin.csv",
  "agentName": "PLC",
  "noOfRecords": 5,
  "data": [
    {
      "accountId": "JKB1234LC",
      "marginValue": "0.00"
    },
    {
      "accountId": "JKB4321LC",
      "marginValue": "1200000.00"
    },
    {
      "accountId": "JKB5678LC",
      "marginValue": "6000000.00"
    },
    {
      "accountId": "JKB8765LC",
      "marginValue": "4000000.00"
    },
    {
      "accountId": "JKB9123LC",
      "marginValue": "0.00"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is my entire LogicApp:

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "CSVTOJSON": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": "@body('Get_blob_content')",
                    "function": {
                        "id": "/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/xxxx-PRD-PORTAL-01/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/jksbmarginrequest/functions/CSVTOJSON"
                    },
                    "method": "POST",
                    "queries": {
                        "fileName": "@triggerBody()?['Name']"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "[Initialize]_For_Composed_AccountId": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Function"
            },
            "Condition": {
                "actions": {
                    "Apply_to_DB": {
                        "actions": {
                            "Execute_stored_procedure_(V2)": {
                                "inputs": {
                                    "body": {
                                        "pActualAccountId": "@{items('Apply_to_DB')?['accountId']}@{variables('var_ComposeAccountIdSuffix')}",
                                        "pAgentId": "@variables('var_AgentName')",
                                        "pEffectiveDate": "@{formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyy-MM-dd')}",
                                        "pMarginVal": "@variables('var_MarginVal')"
                                    },
                                    "host": {
                                        "connection": {
                                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['sql']['connectionId']"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "method": "post",
                                    "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('default'))},@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('default'))}/procedures/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('[dbo].[usp_MarginAddUpdate]'))}"
                                },
                                "runAfter": {
                                    "[Set]_Margin_Value_Float": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                },
                                "type": "ApiConnection"
                            },
                            "[Set]_Margin_Value_Float": {
                                "inputs": {
                                    "name": "var_MarginVal",
                                    "value": "@float(string(variables('var_MarginStr')))"
                                },
                                "runAfter": {
                                    "[Set]_Margin_Value_String": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                },
                                "type": "SetVariable"
                            },
                            "[Set]_Margin_Value_String": {
                                "inputs": {
                                    "name": "var_MarginStr",
                                    "value": "@items('Apply_to_DB')?['marginValue']"
                                },
                                "runAfter": {},
                                "type": "SetVariable"
                            }
                        },
                        "foreach": "@body('Parse_JSON')?['data']",
                        "runAfter": {
                            "For_each": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "Foreach"
                    },
                    "Create_HTML_table": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "format": "HTML",
                            "from": "@body('Parse_JSON')?['data']"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Apply_to_DB": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "Table"
                    },
                    "Execute_a_SQL_query_(V2)": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "body": {
                                "actualParameters": {
                                    "pAgentId": "@variables('var_AgentName')"
                                },
                                "formalParameters": {
                                    "pAgentId": "VARCHAR(10)"
                                },
                                "query": "select * from [dbo].[Parser_MarginFileSettings]\nWhere AgentId =@pAgentId"
                            },
                            "host": {
                                "connection": {
                                    "name": "@parameters('$connections')['sql']['connectionId']"
                                }
                            },
                            "method": "post",
                            "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('default'))},@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('default'))}/query/sql"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {
                            "[Set]_Agent_Name": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "ApiConnection"
                    },
                    "For_each": {
                        "actions": {
                            "[Set]_Composed_Account_ID_with_Suffix": {
                                "inputs": {
                                    "name": "var_ComposeAccountIdSuffix",
                                    "value": "@items('For_each')?['Suffix_AccountId']"
                                },
                                "runAfter": {},
                                "type": "SetVariable"
                            }
                        },
                        "foreach": "@body('Execute_a_SQL_query_(V2)')?['resultsets']?['Table1']",
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Execute_a_SQL_query_(V2)": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "Foreach"
                    },
                    "Parse_JSON": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "content": "@body('CSVTOJSON')",
                            "schema": {
                                "properties": {
                                    "agentName": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "data": {
                                        "items": {
                                            "properties": {
                                                "accountId": {
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                },
                                                "marginValue": {
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "required": [
                                                "accountId",
                                                "marginValue"
                                            ],
                                            "type": "object"
                                        },
                                        "type": "array"
                                    },
                                    "fileName": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "noOfRecords": {
                                        "type": "integer"
                                    }
                                },
                                "type": "object"
                            }
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "ParseJson"
                    },
                    "[Set]_Agent_Name": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "name": "var_AgentName",
                            "value": "@body('Parse_JSON')?['agentName']"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Parse_JSON": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "SetVariable"
                    }
                },
                "else": {
                    "actions": {
                        "Compose_Fail-over_Data": {
                            "inputs": {
                                "File_Name": "@triggerBody()?['Name']",
                                "Message": "@body('CSVTOJSON')",
                                "Status_Code": "@outputs('CSVTOJSON')['statusCode']"
                            },
                            "runAfter": {},
                            "type": "Compose"
                        },
                        "For_Error_Listing": {
                            "inputs": {
                                "format": "HTML",
                                "from": "@outputs('Compose_Fail-over_Data')"
                            },
                            "runAfter": {
                                "Compose_Fail-over_Data": [
                                    "Succeeded"
                                ]
                            },
                            "type": "Table"
                        },
                        "Send_an_email_(V2)": {
                            "inputs": {
                                "body": {
                                    "Body": "<p><u><strong>An Error Occured While Updating Margin Request File<br>\n<br>\n</strong></u><u><strong>@{outputs('Compose_Fail-over_Data')}</strong></u><u><strong></strong></u><br>\n</p>",
                                    "Subject": "Margin File Output",
                                    "To": "itops@jkstock.keells.com"
                                },
                                "host": {
                                    "connection": {
                                        "name": "@parameters('$connections')['office365']['connectionId']"
                                    }
                                },
                                "method": "post",
                                "path": "/v2/Mail"
                            },
                            "runAfter": {
                                "For_Error_Listing": [
                                    "Succeeded"
                                ]
                            },
                            "type": "ApiConnection"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "expression": {
                    "and": [
                        {
                            "equals": [
                                "@outputs('CSVTOJSON')['statusCode']",
                                200
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "CSVTOJSON": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "If"
            },
            "Get_blob_content": {
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/datasets/default/files/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(triggerBody()?['Path']))}/content",
                    "queries": {
                        "inferContentType": true
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "runtimeConfiguration": {
                    "staticResult": {
                        "name": "Get_blob_content0",
                        "staticResultOptions": "Disabled"
                    }
                },
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            },
            "[Initialize]_Agent_Name": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "var_AgentName",
                            "type": "string",
                            "value": "PLC"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Get_blob_content": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "[Initialize]_For_Composed_AccountId": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "var_ComposeAccountIdSuffix",
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "[Initialize]_For_Margin_Value_FLoat": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "[Initialize]_For_Margin_Value_FLoat": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "var_MarginVal",
                            "type": "float",
                            "value": 0
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "[Initialize]_Margin_Value_String": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "[Initialize]_Margin_Value_String": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "var_MarginStr",
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "[Initialize]_Agent_Name": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "staticResults": {
            "Get_blob_content0": {
                "outputs": {
                    "headers": {},
                    "statusCode": "OK"
                },
                "status": "Succeeded"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "When_a_blob_is_added_or_modified_(properties_only)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/datasets/default/triggers/batch/onupdatedfile",
                    "queries": {
                        "folderId": "JTJmcGxj",
                        "maxFileCount": 1
                    }
                },
                "metadata": {
                    "JTJmcGxj": "/plc"
                },
                "recurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Second",
                    "interval": 3
                },
                "splitOn": "@triggerBody()",
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
                "azureblob": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/xxx-PRD-PORTAL-01/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/azureblob-2",
                    "connectionName": "azureblob-2",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/southeastasia/managedApis/azureblob"
                },
                "office365": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/xxx-PRD-PORTAL-01/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/office365",
                    "connectionName": "office365",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/southeastasia/managedApis/office365"
                },
                "sql": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/xxx-PRD-PORTAL-01/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/sql-6",
                    "connectionName": "sql-6",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/southeastasia/managedApis/sql"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try changing your For Each to run one at a time -> turn on Concurrency Control and set Degree of Parallelism to 1.  I have run into issues with For Each and variables because the For Each runs its iterations in parallel and the value you get for the variables are not always from that particular iteration.  See if this solves.  If so, can leave that way or eliminate the use of intermediate variables inside the For Each.

Comment: Have You tried changing . To , might be a classic format issue

Comment: @scott-mildenberger thank you. I noticed the same in few cases. Let me revert you back; but thank you for pointing out.

Comment: @ScottMildenberger Your advice did work out.I can vote your comment as an answer if you could make it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a For Each runs by default it runs iterations concurrently.  The variables are not guaranteed to use the value for the current iteration.  If you change the For Each to run sequentially it will work with the variables.  In the For Each settings turn on Concurrency Control and set the Degree of Parallelism to 1.  The other option is to remove the use of variables in the loop if you want it to run in parallel.

The Microsoft documentation for loop on this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-control-flow-loops says

> To get predictable results from operations on variables during each
>   loop iteration, run those loops sequentially. For example, when a
>   concurrently running loop ends, the increment, decrement, and append
>   to variable operations return predictable results. However, during
>   each iteration in the concurrently running loop, these operations
>   might return unpredictable results.